# Should I use IoC Dependence Injector when developing Business code?

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection, ioc-container

Modern PHP frameworks (like Zend, Symfony, Phalcon) all use a DI container and you simply pass it around to access all the framework functionalities. I'm wondering if I should/could use the DI container in my business code. Let's say I need to use a database access object and a mailer object and they are already in the DI because the framework use them. Could I simply pass the DI container when instantiating a business class?

For example, I have a class that deals with users in the database, you could call it my user model class. Right now I simply pass the DI container to the constructor of the model class when instantiating it in a controller and it's fine and easy. Just toss everything in the DI container and done.

But I'm about to develop an API that will also use this user model class. Since it expects a DI container, I would need to know before hand what the dependencies of the model are and initialize a DI container with the right ones. Before, I would just pass each dependency as a parameter in the constructor but with IoC I need to know, without looking at the parameters, what are the dependencies of the class and what is the name used to access each dependency. For instance, I would need to know that there should be a PDO object identified by 'db' in the DI container. Is this a good approach for business/library code?

I'm probably mixing up terms here but I hope you get the idea.

Thanks!

Comment: this is a good question, reveals how DI easily degrades into a container of global variables.  A good answer could show how to avoid abusing the pattern.

Comment: There's already an answer below, but you largely described the reasons against using a DI container in your question. The frameworks provide the feature because it's easy to use, but they also allow you to properly inject your dependencies which solves the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter what kind of code you are developing, be it business logic or framework logic (or another kind of logic), the entire point here is how you deal with class dependencies.

The term **business logic** itself is very abstractive. You can represent a business logic with a single class (a.k.a [domain object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject)) or you can represent a business logic as a [layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_%28object-oriented_design%29).

### One basic thing to note: Database is just a storage engine

When you develop any application, you should keep in mind that database can be changed (or you could migrate to NoSQL solution in the future). And when/if you do, then `$pdo` is no longer a dependency. If you had storage logic totally decoupled from business one, then it will be easy enough to replace a storage engine. Otherwise you end up rewriting a lot of things when changing it.

A properly designed architecture encourages to decouple storage logic from application logic. Those patterns are established as a best practice: Data Mapper or Table Gateway

```
namespace Storage\MySQL;

use PDO;

abstract class AbstractMapper
{
     protected $pdo;

     public function __construct(PDO $pdo)
     {
            $this->pdo = $pdo;
     }
}

class UserMapper extends AbstractMapper
{
    private $table = 'cms_users';

    public function fetchById($id)
    {
       $query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM `%s` WHERE `id` =:id', $this->table);
       $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
       $stmt->execute(array(
           ':id' => $id
       ));

       return $stmt->fetch();
    }

    // the rest methods that abstract table queries
}
```

So in this case, for the current storage engine `$pdo` is a core dependency and it's not a dependency of a framework or the application you're developing. The next problem you should solve here is how to automatize this process of passing `$pdo` dependency to mappers. There's only one solution you can take advantage of - Factory pattern

```
$pdo = new PDO();
$mapperFactory = new App\Storage\MySQL\Factory($pdo);

$mapperFactory->build('UserMapper'); // will return UserMapper instance with injected $pdo dependency
```

Now let's see obvious benefits:

First of all, it's readability - anyone seeing the code will get the clue, that Mapper is being used to abstract table access. Second you can easily replace a storage engine (if you plan to migrate in future and add several databases support)

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$mapperFactory = new App\Storage\Mongo\Factory($mongo);

$mapperFactory->build('UserMapper'); // will return UserMapper instance with injected $mongo dependency
```

> Note: All mappers for different storage engines should implement one interface (API enforcement)

### Model should not be one class

When it comes to web, we basically do the following:

- Rendering a form (that might look like Contact Page, Login form etc)
- Then submitting a form
- Then comparing against our validation rules
- On success we insert form data into a storage engine, on failure we display error messages

So when you implement a model as a class, then you end up writing validation and storage logic in the same class, therefore tight-coupling and breaking the SRP.

One of this common example, you can see in Yii Framework

A proper model should be a folder of classes containing application logic (see in ZF2 or SF2).

### And finally, should you really use DiC?

Should you use a DI container when developing a code? Well, let's look at this *classical*  code example:

```
class House
{
      public function __construct($diContainer)
      {
             //Let's assume that door and window have their own dependencies
             // So no, it's not a Service Locator in this case
             $this->door = $diContainer->getDoor();
             $this->window = $diContainer->getWindow();
             $this->floor = $diContainer->getFloor();
      }
}

$house = new House($di)
```

In this case you tell that your `House` depends on `DiC` and not explicitly on doors, window and floor. But wait does our `House` really depend on DiC? Surely it doesn't.

And when you start testing your class, you would have also to provide a prepared DiC (which is completely irrelevant)

Usually people use Di containers in order to avoid injection all the time. But from another side, it costs some RAM and some time to parse since most DI containers are configuration based.

Good architecture can be free of any Di container, since it takes advantage of Factories and the SRP.

So good application components should be free of any Service Locators and Di Containers.

Comment: I understand that database is just a storage engine but any database adapter would still be a dependency and I need to bring it up to where I'm gonna call the factory class.

Comment: I much prefer SQL over any ORM, so I use it a lot. What would you think would be the best way to abstract the database code without ending up with an ORM? I want to keep the SQL code easily accessible, I'm not worried about dealing with SQL. Maybe I should post a new question?

Comment: The reason you write pure SQL queries is probably because your queries aren't dynamic, but static. Imagine if you had a table and that table could have 10-15 filters in its `head`. So every time users apply a filter, every time your query is different (say, one user choices to use 1 filter of 10, while another prefers to use 8 filters of 10). Technically that works like this: A form is serialized, then empty values are removed and non-empty ones are used to build SQL query dynamically appending `key=:value AND ..`